# Dealing with Multi-Language Repository (including Go Code)

Tags: git, go

I am currently intending to maintain a single Git-Repository that contains multiple services written in different languages. So far no problem - lately I discovered Go and loved it - so I decided to create a new service in Go and put it into the same repository.

```
src/
   | pythonService/
     > main.py
   | golangService/
     | localGoPackage/
       > someLib.go
     > main.go
     > go.mod
     > go.sum
   | csharpService/
     > some.cs
```

my workflow so far was cloning the Repository to let's say `~/repos/` and copying the Service written in Go to the GOPATH. When changes on code were made, I just copied the changed files back to the Repository and commited the changes. I really wish there was a better way to deal with this.

Then I heard about Go-Modules, which sounded like they would solve this once and for all. However when using GoModules I am not able to reference local-packages inside the goService anymore.

Any recommendations or suggestions from your site on how one could achieve this?

Comment: "I am not able to reference local-packages." What's stopping you? Modules in now way have to consist of a single package.

Comment: You should elaborate on that "…not able to reference local packages". That is, what exactly are you doing to build your code (including all the `cd`s, and calls to `go build`/`go install`), how this fails—with precise error messages, and how the relevant bits of your code look like—the import sections of the affected files are of the most interest.